# wget loop where numbers in URL stay the same

Tags: bash, macos, pdf, terminal, wget

I would like to download a bunch of PDF with `wget` in `bash` (version 3.2.57(1)-release) on a Mac. The PDF represent old newspaper article, which have been published almost every day between 1810 and 1816.

I tried the following command:

```
for i in {10..16}; do wget -A pdf -nc -E -nd —no-check-certificate http://digital.slub-dresden.de/fileadmin/data/453041671-18$i0{1..9}0{1..9}/453041671-18$i0{1..9}0{1..9}_tif/jpegs/453041671-18$i0{1..9}0{1..9}.pdf http://digital.slub-dresden.de/fileadmin/data/453041671-18$i{10..12}{10..31}/453041671-18$i{10..12}{10..31}_tif/jpegs/453041671-18$i{10..12}{10..31}.pdf; done
```

The unfortunate thing is that the URL contains several numbers I need to iterate which let the argument list grow huge until it eventually exceeds the max limit, e. g.

> 453041671-18$i0{1..9}0{1..9}/453041671-18$i0{1..9}0{1..9}_tif/jpegs/453041671-18$i0{1..9}0{1..9}.pdf

and I receive an `argument list too long` error message.

If you take the above link snippet as an example the only existing link would be:

> 453041671-18000701/453041671-18000701_tif/jpegs/453041671-18000701.pdf

where all month have the same number (1800**07**01), unlike this example:

> 453041671-18000**8**01/453041671-18000**7**01_tif/jpegs/453041671-18000**7**01.pdf

or any other combination `wget` is trying.

How can I tell `wget` to set in each iteration of the month `{1..9}` and `{10..12}`, respectively, all numbers the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brace expansions don't know about other brace expansions. You can't have multiple brace expansions and have them change in tandem. Instead, you must use a `for` loop.

```
for year in {10..16}; do
  for month in `seq -w 1 12`; do
    for day in `seq -w 1 31`; do
      wget ... 453041671-18$year$month$day/453041671-18$year$month${day}_tif/jpegs/453041671-18$year$month$day.pdf
      # The second day is in braces because otherwise it would parse as $day_tif.
    done
  done
done
```

In case you want to reduce the number of spawned `wgets`, you can replace `wget` with `echo ... >> listing`, and then use the `--input-file` (`-i`) option to get `wget` to pull URLs from that file.

Comment: Thank you, HTNW, for your reply. It seems to be almost it. However, the second date in the link is off by a year, e. g. `http://digital.slub-dresden.de/fileadmin/data/453041671-18101120/453041671-181120_tif/jpegs/453041671-18101120.pdf.` Edit: I fixed it. `$i`had to be substituted with `$year`

Comment: I found another problem I ran into with `wget` during another project. The brace extensions seem to dismiss a leading zero, for example `http://digital.slub-dresden.de/fileadmin/data/453041671-1810722/453041671-1810722_tif/jpegs/453041671-1810722.pdf`. However it must be `18100722`, but instead wget uses `1810722`. We are almost there!

Comment: Hi, HTNW, I fixed the issue mentioned in the comment above this one by substituting the brace extensions in your script with `seq -w 1 12` and `seq -w 1 31`, respectively.

Comment: Sorry, I'm too used to the `bash`s of Linux distros (Bash v4+). Macs are a full major version behind and can't do zero padding in brace expansions.