# Batch OCR of 5800+ PDF written in German Fraktur

Tags: macos, pdf, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I would like to batch `OCR` about 5800 `PDF` (consisting each between 2 to 6 pages from my last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760828/wget-loop-where-numbers-in-url-stay-the-same)) with open source command line tools on a Mac. The main propose of this adventure is that I want to retrieve as reliable as I can names (surnames most importantly) from the text of all these `PDF`. [Here](http://digital.slub-dresden.de/fileadmin/data/453041671-18100701/453041671-18100701_tif/jpegs/453041671-18100701.pdf) is an example how an issue looks like.

At this point, I do not know exactly how to proceed. What would you do?

I had in mind to first convert all multipage `PDF` to a single page image as either `png`, `jpg`, or `tif` and move all images related to one `PDF` into a respective folder with the following command:

```
time for i in *.pdf; do mkdir "${i%.pdf}"; convert -colorspace GRAY -resize 3000x -units PixelsPerInch  "$i" "${i%.pdf}.jpg”; mv *.jpg "${i%.pdf}"; done
```

As a second step, I would have the issue that my OCR script would need to enter each folder, do its magic, and leave it in order to proceed with the next. I do not know how to write this. The core of the script would be:

```
tesseract --tessdata-dir /usr/local/share/tessdata/ --oem 3 --psm 11 -l deu_frak *.jpg test.txt
```

As the `PDF` represent old newspaper article, which have been published almost every day between 1810 and 1832, they are written in German [Fraktur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur). This font seems to be particularly challenging for `tesseract`. My text output is normally scrambled, e. g. on the above linked article I would get only between 791 to 801 diacritics detected for the first page. Names are at risk not be identified as such depending on the chosen options.

At the end, I would use the [silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) to look for names within all 5800 txt-files, I hope to obtain.

```
time rg -i search_term_here
```

Finally, how can make sure that I get the best possible OCR output so that I obtain most of the (sur)names in the texts?

P.S.: When will by the way [`tesseract 4`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/4.0-with-LSTM) be around for `Mac` and with German Fraktur training data?

**Edit:**

These are the commands, I have used to achieve what I wanted. **Although the output of tesseract could still be improved a great deal.**

Convert each `PDF` into jpg and move them to respective folders to keep order:

```
time parallel -j 8 'mkdir {.} && convert {} -colorspace GRAY -resize 3000x -units PixelsPerInch {.}/{.}.jpg' ::: *.pdf
```

Using Fred's ImageMagick script [textcleaner](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/index.php) (which I have moved to `/usr/local/bin/` for usability), to enhance the tesseract output a bit:

```
time find . -name \*.jpg | parallel textcleaner -g -e stretch -f 25 -o 10 -u -s 1 -T -p 10 {} {}
```

Parallelising the tesseract analyses:

```
time find . -name \*.jpg | parallel -j 8 “tesseract {} {.}.txt —tessdata-dir /usr/local/share/tessdata/ -l deu_frak”
```

Search for the surnames with [the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher):

```
time rg -t txt -i term
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would recommend you install **homebrew** if you have not already - it is an excellent package manager for the Mac.

Then I would recommend you install the **Poppler** package to get the `pdfimages` tool:

```
brew install poppler
```

You can then extract images from a PDF like this:

```
pdfimages SomeFile.pdf root
```

and you will get files named `root-000.ppm` and `root-001.ppm` which will work fine with `tesseract`. Or you can add `-png` if you want PNG images. I would avoid JPEG because of lossy compression.

If you can get that working, I would then suggest you install **GNU Parallel** with:

```
brew install parallel
```

and we can work on doing OCR in parallel down the line.

---

### **PLEASE TRY THE FOLLOWING ONLY IN A SMALL DIRECTORY WITH 5-6 COPIES OF YOUR ORIGINALS**

We can also extract the images in parallel using **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel 'mkdir {.} && pdfimages {} {.}/{.}' ::: *pdf
```

As regards using Fred's `textcleaner` with **GNU Parallel**, and wanting to overwrite the JPEGs, I think you will want something like this:

```
find . -name \*.jpg | parallel textcleaner -g -e stretch -f 25 -o 10 -u -s 1 -T -p 10 {} {}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for replying. I just installed poppler and parallel. However, the ppm I get has a longer quality as my jpg, png, tif I generated before. Only 360 diacritics are detected.

Comment: I don't understand *"longer quality"* - soll daß eine schlechtere Qualität bedeuten, oder eine beßere? Did you resize and greyscale the PPM so that it was comparable in resolution to the images you generated with **ImageMagick**?

Comment: Sry, Mark, I meant lower quality. I did not. Are the options the same for `pdfimages`, e. g. `-colorspace GRAY -resize 3000x -units PixelsPerInch`? With `man pdf images`these options are not indicated.

Comment: Hi Mark, after executing the `parallel` command you posted above, I tried to go a step further and executed `find . -name \*.jpg | parallel 'textcleaner {.} -g -e stretch -f 25 -o 10 -u -s 1 -T -p 10 {.}' ::: *.jpg`. However, `parallel` does not find the `jpg` in the folders. Do you know how to adjust my `parallel` command so that `parallel` goes in each folder and overwrites the existing jpg with the one `textcleaner` creates?

Comment: I had a try at improving your `parallel` command - I think you only want the filenames on `stdin` from the `find` command, not after the triple colons as well. Also, I think you need all the options for `textcleaner` **before** the input file and output file as the **final** two parameters.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me. Note edit in initial post.