# Improve quality of image for tesseract OCR

Tags: macos, pdf, jpeg, ocr, tesseract

With regard to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760828/wget-loop-where-numbers-in-url-stay-the-same) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820673/batch-ocr-of-5800-pdf-written-in-german-fraktur) question, where I ask how to download thousands of `PDF` and processes them to extract their texts with `OCR`, I am hitting a brick wall again when it comes to enhancing the text outputs.

I am interested to extract texts of a bunch of `PDF` in order to search for surnames in the text (I do not need necessarily to be able to read the rest of the text). The `PDF` represent old newspaper articles, published between 1810 and 1832 and written in [German Fraktur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur). This font seems to be particularly challenging for `tesseract`.

**Q: How can I further improve the image quality for `tesseract` to - at least - have a change to find the surnames in the text? Which procedure would you suggest?**

If we take [this](http://digital.slub-dresden.de/fileadmin/data/453041671-18100701/453041671-18100701_tif/jpegs/453041671-18100701.pdf) pdf as an example, I receive the following image when applying

```
convert -colorspace GRAY -resize 3000x -units PixelsPerInch example.pdf example-page.jpg
```

[image]

If I now use `tesseract` with

```
tesseract --tessdata-dir /usr/local/share/tessdata/ -l deu_frak example-page.jpg example-page.txt
```

it would perform terrible on that image with roughly 360 diacritics detected only. My text output is entirely scrambled.

When I use Fred's ImageMagick script [textcleaner](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/), applying either

```
textcleaner -g -e stretch -f 25 -o 10 -u -s 1 -T -p 10
```

or

```
textcleaner -g -e stretch -f 25 -o 20 -t 30 -u -s 1 -T -p 20
```

I get something like this

[image]

When I then run again `tesseract` with the above mentioned command, the resulting text is much better (around 700-800 diacritics detected) but still scrambled enough not to find most surnames of the text.

I know that the example page is a particular hard one, however, even pages, which are not inky prints and not skewed to begin with, yield mostly scrambled outputs and undecipherable surnames when processing them with `tesseract` and the above command.

For example this page

[image]

**Q: How can I further improve the image quality for `tesseract` to - at least - have a change to find the surnames in the text? Which procedure would you suggest?**

**Edit:**
I do not know, whether training tesseract is needed or a good idea to deal with the given German Fraktur font, as GUI box editor seems to work reliably on MacOS, see for example, [jTessBoxEditor](http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html), [Qt-box-editor](https://zdenop.github.io/qt-box-editor/), or [Tesseract-Box-Editor](https://devpost.com/software/tesseract-box-editor), nor did I understand how to train tesseract, see the tesseract training wiki [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract-%E2%80%93-Make-Box-Files) and another tutorial [here](http://pretius.com/how-to-prepare-training-files-for-tesseract-ocr-and-improve-characters-recognition/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My father had a similar problem with his old newspaper clippings, and I had moderately good success by preprocessing with GhostScript and then applying Tesseract.  Your mileage may vary.  My commands (Windows) were

```
set nm=%1
set d=%2
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.21\bin\gswin32.exe" -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pgmraw -r150 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile="%nm%-%%00d.pgm" %nm%.pdf
echo. 2>"%nm%.txt"

for %%f in (%nm%*.pgm) do (
    echo %%~nf
    "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe" "%%~nf.pgm" "%%~nf"
    cat "%%~nf.txt" >> "%nm%.txt"   
    del  "%%~nf.pgm"
    del  "%%~nf.txt"
)
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\winword.exe" "%nm%.txt"
```

EDIT: response to comment

First, install ghostscript on your mac.  See https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Installation_and_Configuration_of_Ghostscript#Installing_Ghostscript_on_Mac_OS_X

Then do

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pgmraw -r150 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile='paper-%00d.pgm' paper.pdf
```

This will create rasterized files paper-01.pgm, paper-02.pgm etc (this is in case your pdf has multiple pages).  You can replace the "paper" with the basename of your original pdf.  You can also mess with the resolution.  That and other things can be found at https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.19/Use.htm

Then use tesseract on each pgm file.

Comment: Hi, mike, thank you for posting. I tried your script, but fail to "translate" it to make it work with mac. Any suggestions on how to make it work for mac?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The last issue I have is, given the vast amount of PDF, that I would like to use GNU parallel with gs. I tried this command `time parallel -j 8 --verbose --progress 'mkdir -p {.} && gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pgmraw -r300 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dOverrideICC -o {.}/{.}.pgm' ::: *.pdf`, which only results in folders (named after each pdf) being empty (where the pgm of the respective PDF supposed to be). Do you know by chance what I do wrong?

Comment: I never got folders, and I am no expert on GNU parallel.  Could you try something low-tech like partitioning your files and forking processes to do each partition sequentially?  Just to see whether it is GNU parallel.

Comment: Hi mikep, I just solved the minor issue. I knew that it was a problem with the syntax of the command. This would be the correct one: `time find . -name \*.pdf | time parallel -j 8 --verbose --progress 'mkdir -p {.} && gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -sDEVICE=pgmraw -r300 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dOverrideICC -o {.}/{.}-%03d.pgm {}'`. Thank you very much for your help!